# NodeJS HTTPS proxy (http-proxy) not picking up on requests

Tags: node.js, https, proxy, http-proxy

I'm trying to make a HTTPS proxy server that intercepts requests in make in my web browser and redirects me somewhere else. The code below, when modified for `http` rather than `https`, works perfectly. However, the program below does not pick up on HTTPS requests at all. Any advice?

```js
const https = require('https');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const url = require('url');
const fs = require('fs');

const sslOptions = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
};

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

const server = https.createServer(sslOptions, (req, res) => {
  const parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url);

  console.log('Original URL:', req.url);
  console.log('Modified URL:', url.format(parsedUrl));

  proxy.web(req, res, {
    target: 'https://' + req.headers.host,
    headers: req.headers,
  });
});

proxy.on('error', (err, req, res) => {
  console.error('Proxy Error:', err);
  res.writeHead(500, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  });
  res.end('Something went wrong.');
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('HTTPS proxy server listening on port 3000');
});
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: A proxy does not get to see the contents of a HTTPS request, because of the end-to-end encryption. The only thing it gets to see is the initial [CONNECT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/CONNECT) request. This is fundamentally different from an HTTP request.